# What is the: Correct way for subtraction in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

[image]How do I get the correct value ?

este value I got from loop is: 2.71828183

actdif =   actval - este

When I subtract, the actdif value is : -4.59045

Entire program is:

```
    PROGRAM est_e

    c       IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER n, lcv
    DOUBLE PRECISION  este, reldif, actdif, factor, actval



    actval = 2.718281828D0
    n=1000
    factor = 1
    este = 1
    DO lcv = 1, n, 1
            factor = factor * lcv
            este = este + 1/factor
    END DO

    actdif =   actval - este
    reldif = actdif/actval


    print *, 'The estimate of e is: ', este
    print *, 'Actual difference is:', actdif
    print *, 'Relative difference is:', reldif
    pause

    END PROGRAM est_e
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your algorithm should do and why the value you get is not what you expect?

Comment: http://ideone.com/FSrrzp  The estimate of e is:    2.7182818284590455     
 Actual difference is:  -4.5904569034860288E-010
 Relative difference is:  -1.6887347206612122E-010

Comment: Are you reading actdif correctly?  Running your code I get `Actual difference is:  -4.5904569034860288E-010` ,that is -4.59 x 10^-10 or -0.00000000045904569034860288

Comment: @High Performance Mark: The pic is not for you. You should leave my thread. We are here to learn, even if it is a silly mistake and not try to prove something, also you are not going to certify me upon anything.

Comment: @Sun You are quite wrong. *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.* Neither your question nor your comments meet the standards on SO.

Comment: @Alexander Vogt: "Neither your question nor your comments meet the standards on", like you answered now ? :-)

If High Performance Mark's comments was not hate speech, then he/she would not have deleted the comment he/she made.

When people want to learn, they will learn, wherever it is. Stackoverflow has done a great job for learners.

Comment: The question is still bad, not because of it being a silly mistake, but because it is badly constructed. Yes, one can probably guess what you are actually asking, but "How do I get the correct value ?" is not a good question. It should first explain what you tried to achieve "I wanted to compute e with the below algorithm: <code>", then "This was the output when I ran it", then what you expected "I was the output to be ...", and then ask a specific question why a certain output is different, and maybe what you tried to figure out yourself. Please, put some more effort into asking a question.

Comment: Thank you steabert. Like you suggested, I will try be more efficient and clear in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply mis-reading your output. You claim that the output is:

```
-4.59045
```

That claim is contradicted by the screenshot. The actual output is:

```
-4.5904569E-10
```

That is a very small number, very close to zero. Note also that your actual value is specified to 10 significant digits, commensurate with the relative error that your program reports.  In other words it seems that your estimate is accurate and that your program is behaving correctly.

Comment: Now, I understand my mistake. I am new to these concepts and Fortran. I was checking it by using the calculator and it showed "-0.000000002" as answer. I was confused with that. Is there any other possibility to display the answer in a better way ? Thank you David !

Comment: I understand E Notation. Thank you Peter.

Comment: Yes, you are right David. But, I thought I could display it like 0.000000... instead of showing it in as "E-10". But, it is fine. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: There are certainly ways to output values in fixed format rather than scientific notation. http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/17_format.html  http://math.hawaii.edu/wordpress/fortran-3/#write  I'm sure that your Fortran text book will cover this in lots of detail.

Comment: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html

I think, I have to use "Write( )" format statement, I will see through these.

Comment: I will study these materials. Thank you for your guidance David.